# Number of permutations with a given constraint

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $\Pi$ be the set of all permutations of the set $\left\{1 \ldots n\right\}$. Of course I know the cardinal of $\Pi$ is $n!$.

I am trying to compute the number of permutations $\pi = \left\{ \pi_1, \ldots \pi_n \right\} \in \Pi $ that verify that the *maximum* distance between any two *consecutive* permuted elements is lower than a given constant $M$.

This is, I want to compute the cardinal of the set $\Pi^M = \left\{ \pi = \left\{ \pi_1, \ldots \pi_n \right\}, \max(|\pi_i - \pi_{i+1} |) < M , \forall i,i+1 \in \left\{1\ldots n\right\}\right\}$

Also, is there an algorithm to efficiently compute such a subset $\Pi^M$ of $\Pi$?

Maybe an example explains better the $\Pi^M$ set, with $n=4$ and $M=2$:

- $ \left\{1, 2, 3, 4 \right\} \in \Pi^2$ as all elements have a distance of one.
  But
- $ \left\{4, 1, 2, 3 \right\} \notin \Pi^2$ because elements 4 and 1 have a distance of 3.

Comment: If $M\ge n$  every permutation is a solution, else there is none. Do you see why? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm interested in the $M<n$ case only. Thansk for the comment!

Comment: You are welcome! For the $M<n$ case, take $i,j$ such that $\pi_i=1,\pi_j=n$.

Comment: Thanks again :-) I forgot the 'max' in the definition.

Comment: [This answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63236/number-of-a-certain-type-of-permutations/63248#63248) is for the case $M=1$, and proves that the cardinal of $\Pi^1$ is $2^{n-1}$. That's good enough for me!